# How can I configure Open Build Service to keep more than one package on the repositories?

Tags: open-build-service

Open Build Service (OBS), currently only keeps the latest package it builds in the repository. Is there a server-wide configuration I can set to keep the latest 3 packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this can be done yet,

From Libera IRC `#openSUSE-buildservice`

```
13:58 < EvanCarroll> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656627/how-can-i-configure-open-build-service-to-keep-more-than-one-package-on-the-repo
13:59 < anyone> that's not in the design.
```

So I opened a [feature request to track this](https://github.com/openSUSE/open-build-service/issues/11323).